# Convert for loop to do while loop

Tags: loops

i am new in programming and i want to know how to convert for loops to do while loops

```
for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(int k=r;k>i;k--)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        int number = 1;
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {

             System.out.print(number+" ");
             number = number * (i - j) / (j + 1);

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Please see my coding below. Actually I am pretty much confused on how to convert it to DO-WHILE Loop.

Comment: What language is this, Java? Please edit your post and include the tag for the language used. Otherwise people won't be able to find or read your question.

Comment: Also, converting for loops to while loops is a very bad idea no matter programming language. Generally, simple for loops that iterate over a known amount of items are the most readable form of loops, which also tend to produce the fastest possible code. While loops should only be used when the number of iterations isn't known in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of a do while loop is as follows:

```
do {

 some iterative function

} while (some condition is true);
```

A do-while loop will execute the code at least once before evaluating the condition. Keep this in mind while implementing.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you can't. They are incommensurable. A `for` loop executes zero or more times, as it tests at the top. A `do/while` loop executes one or more times, i.e. at least once, as it tests at the bottom. You can only correctly convert `for` to `do/while` if you know the condition is initially `true`.

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to handle `while` loops instead if `for` like loops is :

`for(int i=0; i<10; i++){   ......   }`
can also be given as

```
do
{
  .....;
  i++;
}while(i<10)
```

OR

```
while(i<10)
{
   .....;
   i++;
}
```

Comment: in a `for` loop, you simply mention all the increments in the loop line itself, whereas in a `while` loop should only have the condition of running the loop inside the parenthesis next to the word `while` and the increment condition at the end of your statements inside the while loop. `Do While` is a little different in a way that, it will execute the code inside at least once even before checking whether it should do so or not.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you move the initialization statement to before the do-while, put the increment statement inside the do-while and put the termination condition as the while condition. I.e.

```
//the innermost loop
int number = 1;
j = 0;  //initialization statement
do
{
    System.out.print(number + " ");
    number = number * (i -j)/(j + 1);
    j++; //increment statement
}
while(j < i /* termination condition */);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a `for` loop similar to this:

```
for (int i = a; i < b; i++) {
    // Body
}
```

Then you know it executes the body `b-a` times (barring any modifications to `i` within the body.

So you translate it to:

```
int i = a;
if (i < b) {
    do {
    // Body
        i++;
    } while (i < b);
}
```

Note that you have to wrap the `do { ... } while( ... )` in an `if-else` as `do-while` loops will execute the body at least once which is not true for `for` loops.

In general, if you have a `for(initial_condition; boolean_expr; incr)` loop, the `do-while` equivalent would be

```
initial_condition;
if (boolean_expr) {
    do {
        // Body
        incr;
    } while (boolean_expr);
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is `j` here?

Comment: @EJB I originally had `for(int i = 0;i < j;i++)` but forgot to change it after I modified the for loop